# Index Match multiple criteria and multiple rows google sheets

Tags: arrays, indexing, google-sheets, excel-formula, match

I am trying to match date and time, and metric category with multiple rows in a data sheet. Currently, I record metrics every day in a similar function with a set of rows showing metric data based on intervals of time. These rows are broken up by date.

I would like to be able to add to a dashboard the current metrics without someone needing to dig through the tables I am recording in. This would require the metric to stay up there until the next interval changed.

I will use =SPLIT(NOW) for the date and time but for now I would like to at least get this to work with static interval and date. I tried using Index Match using AND(), & etc and I cannot get it to work. I also tried to use an array but it errors every time.

[Google Sheets Index Match Multi Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OweVP.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the time intervals for each day will be exactly the same and the data structure will never change  with 3 identical lines per day (as per your screenshot) than I think you are overcomplicating things a little:

B2:

```
 =index($A$7:$E$15,MATCH($A$1,$A$7:$A$15,0)+1,MATCH(B$1,$A$7:$E$7,0))
```

B3:

```
 =index($A$7:$E$15,MATCH($A$1,$A$7:$A$15,0)+2,MATCH(B$1,$A$7:$E$7,0))
```

B4:

```
 =index($A$7:$E$15,MATCH($A$1,$A$7:$A$15,0)+2,MATCH(B$1,$A$7:$E$7,0))
```

[image]